# How to fill the space between two floating divs?

Tags: html, css

I have code:
`<th colspan="3" />`
`<div class="l_table_th" /></div>`
   `<div class="c_table_th" />Zamów pakiet punktów</div>`
   `<div class="r_table_th"/ ></div>`
`</th>`

left and right div's are necessary for rounded corners (by background, no CSS3) of HEADER for table. 
And my problem is: how to make center div fill all the space between them?
width: 100% makes right div is falling to the next line. width: auto makes center div too short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting margins (left and right) for central `<div>`. Assuming that `.l_table_th` and `.r_table_th` are 15px wide, something like this should work:

```
<th colspan="3" />
   <div class="l_table_th"></div>
   <div class="r_table_th"></div>
   <div class="c_table_th">Zamów pakiet punktów</div>
</th>

.c_table_th {
    margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
}

.l_table_th {
    width: 15px;
    float: left;
}

.r_table_th {
    width: 15px;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap them in another div apply a background color?

Comment: background is with gradient. And moreover, side divs have their own bacgrounds.

Comment: Are the side divs transparent? Because otherwise, I don't see why you couldn't put the background on the `TH` or a container `DIV`. Usually, the idea is that you set a background on the container, then you have your end-pieces floated left/right, and then the center element is just there to hold the text, and it will expand to accommodate the text, but doesn't need to fill the entire area.

Comment: you can use an image as a background to fill the space